# Empty the content of a div using jQuery. Can not make it work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this example that allow me to draw into the canvas. http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/649/example2.html

However, I want to have a button that clears the content of it. This is what I did without luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#clearme").click(function() {
       var view = $('#imageView');
       var context = view[0].getContext('2d');
       context.clearRect(550, 550, view.width(), view.height());
      });
    });

<a href="#" id="clearme">clear</a>

<div id="container">
      <canvas id="imageView" width="610" height="680">
      </canvas>
</div>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The answers provided should work; as for why `.empty` does not work: it empties the element by removing its children. Since a canvas does not have children it doesn't do much. Clearing the canvas visually doesn't modify the DOM.

Comment: @pimvdb I have updated it with an actual solution, but again, I don't get any result.

Comment: What about replacing `550` with `0`? Clearing the whole canvas means starting at `(0, 0)` (top left).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear the canvas via its API instead:

```
var view = $('#imageView');
var context = view[0].getContext('2d');
context.clearRect(0, 0, view.width(), view.height());
```

Comment: Thank you, I have replaced the `$('#imageView').empty();` with what you have posted me, without a result. Can you provide me more code?

Comment: you have to replace width and height with the actual width and height of the canvas, something like:
`context.clearRect(0, 0, $('#imageView').width(), $('#imageView').height());`

Comment: Yes, I should've mentioned that those were placeholder values. I updated the example, thanks user306848.

Comment: I have updated my question with the updated answers but without any result. Can you take a look at it please?

Comment: You need to use `0, 0` as the first two parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You have to clear the canvas, `empty()` is not what you're looking for. Do something like this:

```
var ctx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height);
ctx.beginPath();
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the updated answers but without any result. Can you take a look at it please?

Answer (score 1):

Empty() wont clear a canvas. You'll have to use clearRect.

Comment: I have updated my question with the updated answers but without any result. Can you take a look at it please?